# Stripe creating Checkout session throws error ( Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException Invalid array )

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I've been trying to create a checkout session for a payment which should be directed in connected account.
whenever I'm trying to create a session using the code below I get `InvalidRequestException` saying `Invalid array`

Here's my code below,

```
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
    
    $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

    $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([       
      'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
      'line_items' => [
        'price_data' => [
              'unit_amount' => 25000,
              'currency' => 'usd',
              'product_data' => ['name' => 'Product8', 'active' => true],
            ],
        'quantity' => 2,
      ],
      'mode' => 'payment',
      'success_url' => 'http://devweb.drivinggradebook.com/',
      'cancel_url' => 'https://www.drivinggradebook.com/',
      'payment_intent_data' => [
        'application_fee_amount' => 10,
      ],
    ], ['stripe_account' => 'acct_1L7ugjSJzLhcy6eF']);
```

Please help me out with it,
Thanks

Comment: Try changing `'payment_method_types' => ['card'],` to `'payment_method_types[]' => 'card',` and tell me what it does then.

Comment: @geertjanknapen tried changing, still getting the same error

Comment: Have you tried removing some of the parameters to identify where exactly the error is occurring? Try with the bare minimum to create a session and see if that goes through successfully. If it does, start adding more parameters to your array. If it doesn't work, reach out to the developer of the stripe package you're using.

Comment: I was just supposed to add one more extra square bracket inside the line_items like this,   'line_items' => [ [ 'price_data' => [ ], 'quantity' => 1, ],  ],

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have it running as follows with laravel 8.75 and stripe/stripe-php 10.1

```
public function checkout(Request $request)
{
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_SECRET);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
        'line_items'  => [
            [
                'price_data' => [
                    'currency'     => 'eur',
                    'product_data' => [
                        'name' => 'Home'
                    ],
                    'unit_amount'  => 500
                ],
                'quantity'   => 1
            ],
        ],
        'mode'        => 'payment',
        'success_url' => url("/stripe_success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}&tenant_id=$request->id"),
        'cancel_url'  => route('payments.index'),
    ]);

    return redirect()->away($checkout_session->url);
}
```